# expression engine SEO URL disable option?

Tags: php, expressionengine, seo

i need to disable the default functionality of expression engine to create the URL, i can't figure out an option to disable it? even removed everything from htaccess did't resolve..

Answer (score 0):

Set the option AllowOverride to None in the virtual host file and the complete .htaccess file will be ignored.

Comment: facing this error after setting NONE; " Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. "

Comment: The redirects to errordocuments can be handled in the apache configuration documents. If you did not do that, then will you get this error indeed. More information can be found at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html